# MVC3 - Partial Views and server validation of their associated model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model

I'm pretty new to MVC3 and have a question about the auto validation of models undertaken at the server side.

My scenario:
Index page that has a partial view (lets call it partial A) and associated model, say, customer name.  Within this partial view is another partial view (lets call it Partial B) that allows the customers to enter any previous names they have (i.e. maiden name details) which has its own model.

Now Partial B is optional in that the user does not have to enter details unless they want to, whereas Partial A details must be entered.

When pressing the submit button, the form which encloses both Partial views fires the controller and relevant action/method - MVC3 automatically validates Partial A model.  If I pass both models as parameters to the action, then both are validated.

However, I want to validate Partial A model everytime and only Partial B model if the customer has added details.

So, I would like to know what the best method to take to code for this scenario.
I can see that the form tag attributes could be change by jquery/javascript by checking if details have been entered on Partial B and then change the action/method call to one that takes both models as input.  Is this the best way, or is there another way that is better?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may  disable the partial page b controls and enable them if user want to enter them. as disable controls don't get validated. The other option that may use is to use conditional validation. You may google conditional validation for asp.net mvc and you get many links for reference you may see [here](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) and 
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Following a slight misunderstanding of the question in my previous answer, user1079925 stated in the comment that the data would now be provided in a single model.  Therefore, I have provided this alternative solution using custom data annotations for this single model approach (the previous answer will be deleted):

This example assumes that the user will enter forename, middlename and surname.  If either of the middlename or surname are entered then the forename must be entered.

**Model:**

```
public class IndexModel
{
    [RequiredIfOtherFieldEntered("MiddleName", "Surname", ErrorMessage="Please enter the forename")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

**IndexView:**

```
@model MvcApplication6.Models.IndexModel

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Forename: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Forename) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Forename)</p>

    <p>If you enter the middle name or the surname then the forename will be required.</p>

    <p>Middlename: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MiddleName)</p>

    <p>Surname: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Surname)</p>

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexModel indexModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NextPage");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomAttribute:**

```
public class RequiredIfOtherFieldEnteredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string[] properties;

    public RequiredIfOtherFieldEnteredAttribute(params string[] properties)
    {
        if (properties == null && properties.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("properties");
        }

        this.properties = properties;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach (string property in properties)
        {
            //using System.Reflection.PropertyInfo;
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(property);

            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Property '{0}' is undefined.", property));
            }

            var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (propertyValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyValue.ToString()))
            {
                if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                    return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```